# Convert hyphens to camel case (camelCase)

Tags: javascript, regex, camelcasing

With regex (i assume) or some other method, how can i convert things like:

`marker-image` or `my-example-setting` to `markerImage` or `myExampleSetting`.

I was thinking about just splitting by `-` then convert the index of that hypen +1 to uppercase. But it seems pretty dirty and was hoping for some help with regex that could make the code cleaner.

*No* jQuery...

Comment: Exact duplicate of [JavaScript RegExp $1 to upper case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969605/javascript-regexp-1-to-upper-case)

Comment: it is actually, but i searched and never found it probably due to the obscure name. Id suggest keeping this open so people can actually find the answer. "RegExp $1 to uppercase"... no one is going to find it unless they already knew regex IMO

Comment: That was easily fixable. I just edited the title

Comment: So a cut and paste of the solutions would have earned me an accepted answer :|

Comment: is there a way to do the exact opposite?

Comment: Circa 2019 It's ALWAYS a good DRY idea for such basic questions to see what is in sindresorhus' library  first, https://npms.io/search?q=author%3Asindresorhus+camel     Sindresorhus has literally hundreds of small, single purpose, and maintained packages covering all the basics and more

Comment: No jQuery... this should be or get at least a standard nowadays

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Try this:

```
var camelCased = myString.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
```

The regular expression will match the `-i` in `marker-image` and capture only the `i`. This is then uppercased in the callback function and replaced.

Comment: FYI, here's the opposite : `myString.replace(/([a-z][A-Z])/g, function (g) { return g[0] + '-' + g[1].toLowerCase() });`

Comment: I think that the parameter should be renamed to "m", like "match".
One can quickly write something like :
    `myString.replace(/-([a-z])/i, function (i) { return i[1].toUpperCase() });`

Comment: It would be a good idea to make your regex more robust by adding the `i` flag. Without it, your pattern misses "capitalized-Parts" (won't be changed into "capitalizedParts"). Also,  I personally prefer the improved readability of multiple parameters, but that's obviously a matter of style. All in all, I'd go with `.replace( /-([a-z])/gi, function ( $0, $1 ) { return $1.toUpperCase(); } );`.

Comment: To add upon this, if you want to camel case *space separated* words as well, the following would work: `var camelCased = myString.replace(/(-+|\s+)\w/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });`

Comment: @wolfram77, You include multiple dashes/space characters in the regexp, then uppercase the second character of the match, meaning if the second character is a space or dash, it is the one getting uppercased. How about this: `var camelCased = myString.replace(/(-+|\s+)\w/g, function (g) { return g[g.length - 1].toUpperCase(); });`?

Comment: @trysis i deliberately made a mistake to see if anyone can notice. good! :)

Comment: a wee bit shorter: `str.replace(/-./g, c => c. substring(1).toUpperCase())`

Comment: @StLia note (for others as you probably already know): this also matches marker-Image, my-Example-Setting, my-1st-Example-With-a-Number, ... Someone might not want that :)

Answer (score 54):

This is one of the great utilities that [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#camelCase) offers if you are enlightened and have it included in your project.

```
var str = 'my-hyphen-string';
str = _.camelCase(str);
// results in 'myHyphenString'
```

Comment: This fails on this condition: var str = 'my-hyphen-string:';

Answer (score 20):

You can get the hypen and the next character and replace it with the uppercased version of the character:

```
var str="marker-image-test";
str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (m, w) {
    return w.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: Nice - I went with this method but ES6'd it into >> str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (x, up) => up.toUpperCase())

Answer (score 16):

Here's my version of camelCase function:

```
var camelCase = (function () {
    var DEFAULT_REGEX = /[-_]+(.)?/g;

    function toUpper(match, group1) {
        return group1 ? group1.toUpperCase() : '';
    }
    return function (str, delimiters) {
        return str.replace(delimiters ? new RegExp('[' + delimiters + ']+(.)?', 'g') : DEFAULT_REGEX, toUpper);
    };
})();
```

It handles all of the following edge cases:

- takes care of both underscores and hyphens by default (configurable with second parameter)
- string with unicode characters
- string that ends with hyphens or underscore
- string that has consecutive hyphens or underscores

Here's a link to live tests: http://jsfiddle.net/avKzf/2/

Here are results from tests:

- input: "ab-cd-ef", result: "abCdEf"
- input: "ab-cd-ef-", result: "abCdEf"
- input: "ab-cd-ef--", result: "abCdEf"
- input: "ab-cd--ef--", result: "abCdEf"
- input: "--ab-cd--ef--", result: "AbCdEf"
- input: "--ab-cd-__-ef--", result: "AbCdEf"

Notice that strings that start with delimiters will result in a uppercase letter at the beginning.
If that is not what you would expect, you can always use lcfirst.
Here's my lcfirst if you need it:

```
function lcfirst(str) {
    return str && str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)'s [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal and a replacement function.

For example:

```
'uno-due-tre'.replace(/-./g, (m) => m[1].toUpperCase()) // --> 'unoDueTre'
```

Explanation:

- `'uno-due-tre'` is the (input) string that you want to convert to camel case.
- `/-./g` (the first argument passed to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal.

  - The `'-.'` (between the slashes) is a pattern. It matches a single `'-'` character followed by any single character. So for the string `'uno-due-tre'`, the pattern `'-.'` matches `'-d'` and `'-t'` .
  - The `'g'` (after the closing slash) is a flag. It stands for "global" and tells [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to perform a global search and replace, ie, to replace all matches, not just the first one.
- `(m) => m[1].toUpperCase()` (the second argument passed to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) is the replacement function. It's called once for each match. Each matched substring is replaced by the string this function returns. `m` (the first argument of this function) represents the matched substring. This function returns the second character of `m` uppercased. So when `m` is `'-d'`, this function returns `'D'`.
- `'unoDueTre'` is the new (output) string returned by [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The input string is left unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't scream out for a `RegExp` to me. Personally I try to avoid regular expressions when simple string and array methods will suffice:

```
let upFirst = word => 
  word[0].toUpperCase() + word.toLowerCase().slice(1)

let camelize = text => {
  let words = text.split(/[-_]/g) // ok one simple regexp.
  return words[0].toLowerCase() + words.slice(1).map(upFirst)
}

camelize('marker-image') // markerImage
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my implementation (just to make hands dirty)

```
/**
 * kebab-case to UpperCamelCase
 * @param {String} string
 * @return {String}
 */
function toUpperCamelCase(string) {
  return string
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('-')
    .map(it => it.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + it.substring(1))
    .join('');
}
```

Comment: Please note that substr is now deprecated, better use substring method in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Turn the dash separated variable name into camelCase.
str = str.replace(/\b-([a-z])/g, (_, char) => char.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that combines a couple answers here and makes it method on a string:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.toCamel !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.toCamel = function(){
    return this.replace(/[-_]([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); })
  };
}
```

Used like this:

```
'quick_brown'.toCamel(); // quickBrown
'quick-brown'.toCamel(); // quickBrown
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take.

> Used when...

```
var string = "hyphen-delimited-to-camel-case"
or
var string = "snake_case_to_camel_case"


function toCamelCase( string ){
  return string.toLowerCase().replace(/(_|-)([a-z])/g, toUpperCase );
}

function toUpperCase( string ){
  return string[1].toUpperCase();
}

Output: hyphenDelimitedToCamelCase
```

Answer (score 0):

is also possible use indexOf with recursion for that task.

```
input some-foo_sd_dsd-weqe
output someFooSdDsdWeqe
```

comparison ::: measure execution time for two different scripts:

```
$ node camelCased.js
someFooSdDsdWeqe
test1: 2.986ms
someFooSdDsdWeqe
test2: 0.231ms
```

code:

```
console.time('test1');
function camelCased (str) {

        function check(symb){

            let idxOf = str.indexOf(symb);
            if (idxOf === -1) {
                return str;
            }

            let letter = str[idxOf+1].toUpperCase();
            str = str.replace(str.substring(idxOf+1,idxOf+2), '');
            str = str.split(symb).join(idxOf !== -1 ? letter : '');

            return camelCased(str);
        }       

        return check('_') && check('-');

    }

console.log(camelCased ('some-foo_sd_dsd-weqe'));
console.timeEnd('test1');



console.time('test2');

    function camelCased (myString){
     return myString.replace(/(-|\_)([a-z])/g, function (g) { return  g[1].toUpperCase(); });
   }


console.log(camelCased ('some-foo_sd_dsd-weqe'));
console.timeEnd('test2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a version with flag, for loop and without Regex:

```
function camelCase(dash) { 

  var camel = false;
  var str = dash;
  var camelString = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) === '-'){
      camel = true;

    } else if(camel) {
      camelString += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
      camel = false;
    } else {
      camelString += str.charAt(i);
    }
  } 
  return camelString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [camelcase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase) from NPM.

`npm install --save camelcase`

```
const camelCase = require('camelcase');
camelCase('marker-image'); // => 'markerImage';
camelCase('my-example-setting'); // => 'myExampleSetting';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you **allow numbers** in your string.

Obviously the parts that begin with a number will not be capitalized, but this might be useful in some situations.

```
function fromHyphenToCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([a-z0-9])/g, (g) => g[1].toUpperCase())
}
```

```js
function fromHyphenToCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([a-z0-9])/g, (g) => g[1].toUpperCase())
}

const str1 = "category-123";
const str2 = "111-222";
const str3 = "a1a-b2b";
const str4 = "aaa-2bb";

console.log(`${str1} => ${fromHyphenToCamelCase(str1)}`);
console.log(`${str2} => ${fromHyphenToCamelCase(str2)}`);
console.log(`${str3} => ${fromHyphenToCamelCase(str3)}`);
console.log(`${str4} => ${fromHyphenToCamelCase(str4)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string and array methods; I used trim to avoid any spaces.

```
const properCamel = (str) =>{

  const lowerTrim = str.trim().toLowerCase(); 

  const array = lowerTrim.split('-');

  const firstWord = array.shift();

  const caps = array.map(word=>{

    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  })

  caps.unshift(firstWord)

  return caps.join('');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution takes into account these edge cases.

- Single word
- Single letter
- No hyphen
- More than 1 hyphen

`` const toCamelCase = (text) => text.replace(/(.)([^-|$]*)[-]*/g, (_,letter,word) => `${letter.toUpperCase()}${word.toLowerCase()}`) ``