# Capitalise first letter in each string of an array and remove '_' character

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an array which looks something like:

```
["image", "image_link", "images_carousel", "images_collection", "video", "video_carousel", "video_collection", "video_link"]
```

I need to capitalise the first letter of each word and remove the "_" between some words.
I've managed to do it for a string but I can't get it for this array. some help? Thanks.

Comment: `const newArr = yourArr.map(function(text) { /* change text here and return it */ });`

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: See [this specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53823336/519413) answer in the first duplicate for the best way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
yourArray.map(word => `${word.charAt[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}`.replace(/_/g, " "));
```

Comment: Please let OP know how this fixes her/his problem.