# Convert hyphenated string to CamelCase

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm trying to convert a hyphenated string to CamelCase string.  I followed this post: [Convert hyphens to camel case (camelCase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660977/convert-hyphens-to-camel-case-camelcase)

```
(defn hyphenated-name-to-camel-case-name [^String method-name]
  (clojure.string/replace method-name #"-(\w)" 
                          #(clojure.string/upper-case (first %1))))


(hyphenated-name-to-camel-case-name "do-get-or-post")
==> do-Get-Or-Post
```

Why I'm still getting the dash the output string?

Comment: You misread what was being used in the replacement function, array indices in JavaScript start at 0 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should replace `first` with `second`:

```
(defn hyphenated-name-to-camel-case-name [^String method-name]
  (clojure.string/replace method-name #"-(\w)" 
                          #(clojure.string/upper-case (second %1))))
```

You can check what argument `clojure.string/upper-case` gets by inserting `println` to the code:

```
(defn hyphenated-name-to-camel-case-name [^String method-name]
  (clojure.string/replace method-name #"-(\w)" 
                          #(clojure.string/upper-case
                            (do
                              (println %1)
                              (first %1)))))
```

When you run the above code, the result is:

```
[-g g]
[-o o]
[-p p]
```

The first element of the vector is the matched string, and the second is the captured string, 
which means you should use `second`, not `first`.

Answer (score 6):

In case your goal is just to to convert between cases, I really like the [camel-snake-kebab](https://github.com/qerub/camel-snake-kebab) library.  `->CamelCase` is the function-name in question.

Answer (score 1):

inspired by [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/QhUq3Ua4UaA), you could also do

```
(use 'clojure.string)

(defn camelize [input-string] 
  (let [words (split input-string #"[\s_-]+")] 
    (join "" (cons (lower-case (first words)) (map capitalize (rest words))))))
```