# Applying a transformation to a captured group

Tags: javascript

Can I apply a transformation to a captured group and perform a replacement in ES5?

I would like to transform dashed names (e.g. 'foo-bar) to camelcase (e.g. 'fooBar').

```
function camelify(str) {
  return (str.replace(/(\-([^-]{1}))/g, '$2'.toUpperCase()));
}
```

Comment: see also [Convert hyphens to camel case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6660977/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'$2'.toUpperCase()`, the second argument you pass in, is equivalent to `'$2'` which does nothing but remove the dash.

You are looking for the [callback parameter option in `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
function camelify(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([^-])/g, function(match, $1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```